# Subprocess Call behaving strangely when called in a GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, subprocess

I have a button in my GUI (I used PyQt4, I don't know if that's relevant) that calls `subprocess.call()` to run an outside executable.

Some background on the outside executable: it is a Fortran program that takes two inputs, an input file, and an output file. The output file is an empty one and is where the results are written. Here is a short script I wrote to test it out:

```
import subprocess

path_to_executable = r"L:\internal\684.84\path\masscomp.exe"
input_path =  r"L:\internal\684.84\path\file1.ntxt"
output_path = r"L:\internal\684.84\path\file1.nout"

subprocess.call([path_to_executable, input_path, output_path])
```

When I tested this out, it worked perfectly. This is how I incorporated it into my GUI. The user picks the files they want analyzed, and the paths to these files are stored in a `QListWidget`. I then put these paths in a list, and I loop through the list, running each file through the executable. Here's the code:

```
def click_analyze(self):

        path_to_executable = r"L:\internal\684.07\path\masscomp.exe"
        for n in range(self.ui.inputList.count()):

            input_path = str(self.ui.inputList.item(n).text())
            output_path = input_path.replace('.ntxt', '.nout')

            # print input_path, '\n', output_path
            # L:\internal\684.84\path\file1.ntxt
            # L:\internal\684.84\path\file1.nout 
            # These are right

            subprocess.check_call([path_to_executable, input_path, output_path])
```

This method runs when a button is clicked. However, the executable returns an error. Something is wrong with the input file. I ran the exact same file through my script, and it worked perfectly.

**My question is:**
Is `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.check_call` any different when called in the GUI? Could it be that in my script I use a raw string literal and when I get it from the `QListWidget` it isn't the same?

I realize this is impossible to reproduce because you don't have the outside executable, but I just wanted to see if there was some problem other than that. Thanks

Comment: I've added the [tag:python2.7] tag from the syntax of your commented out print statement, if you are using a different version please edit the tags appropriately as it may be relevant.

Comment: The call to `subprocess.check_call` is in a loop, is it possible that one of the iterations works correctly and another one fails?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I tried it with only one item in the list and with multiple, and they all fail. Btw, thank you for adding the tag

Comment: based on the `.replace('.ntxt', '.nout')` I'd expect the input of `\input1.ntxt` to be changed to `\input1.nout` not `\output1.nout` so I'll need you to at least check your paths again, maybe just check `assert output_path = r"L:\internal\684.84\path\output1.nout"` or the similar.

Comment: Err I actually just changed the names to illustrate the problem. In the program the output and input have the same names; the only difference is the ending (`.ntxt` vs `.nout`) I updated the question so it's more clear, sorry about that

Comment: @PeterWang. You should get a `CalledProcessError` from `check_call`, so please edit your question and show the **full** traceback.

Comment: @ekhumoro nothing is wrong with the `call` or `check_call`; there is no Python error. The executable that I'm using has an output that tells you if it was successful or not. It's successful in the script, and it says there was an error when run from the GUI. The error is that the input file isn't the same, which is strange because the input file is the same in the script and from the GUI

Comment: @PeterWang. Well, there *should* be an error: obviously the executable is poorly designed in that regard. But anyway, my request still stands. You should include all the error messages in your question (whether they come from python or not). The input paths clearly *cannot* be the same, otherwise there would be no error. What is the output of: `print repr(input_path)`?